# JQuery TableSorter Comma-Digit Parser not working

Tags: sorting, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

Here's my problem,

I am currently using the JQuery Table Sorter and I found a Comma-Digit parser on the web.  The problem I am having is it doesn't seem to be working.

So here is what the column is sorted as:

1. 4,666
2. 141,666
3. 293
4. 341,666
5. 346
6. 461,676

This should be sorted as

1. 293
2. 346
3. 4,666
4. 141,666
5. 341,666
6. 461,676

The parser I am using is this:

```
$( function() { 

    $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "fancyNumber",
        is: function(s) {
            return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
        },
        format: function(s) {
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
        },
        type: "numeric"
    });
});
```

I just don't know I am doing wrong.  Am I loading it wrong? Is the parser wrong?  I need real help here and have been struggling with this problem for a while now.

**Edit:** Because of how I generate my columns and the columns allowed to be chosen by the user, I would never know which header is in and not.  I have tried using the class="{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}"  command as stated here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html

**Edit:**It looks like one of the columns is working correctly, but this column is still having problems.  maybe because it has digits and comma seperated digits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone that comes across this question.  I had to add the class to my header row.  So for any header that I wanted to fancy sort, I added this class:

```
<th class=\"{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}\">
```

This turned on the sorter by default which made it work nice.

What made me realize my error in my ways was turning on the debugger like so.

```
$("#tblInfo").tablesorter({debug:true, widgets: ['zebra'], widgetZebra: { css: ['d0', 'd1']} });
```

Comment: You don't have to do this.  The headers option allows you to specify the data type.  Look http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html there and see.  In your options you just specify `headers: { 5: 'mysorter' }` and hey presto.

Comment: This is no good though when you have a dynamic number of columns. E.g. sometimes this column is column 5 in one table and column 4 in another table. By putting it into the TH directly, you ensure it works everywhere. I don't like specifying column numbers numerically hardcoded.

Comment: This works as advertised, but make sure to add the jquery.metadata.js lib, as its required for specifying inline options.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-metadata

Comment: I was wondering why my `class="{sorter: 'numeric'}"` didn't work; I had not put in the `<th>` entry! Obvious when thought of, but I didn't spot it at first. Your post helped me, thanks!

Comment: thanks for this was very helpful troubleshooting my own build!

Answer (score 3):

This can also happen if you forget to include the metadata plugin

** Posted here since this was the first search result on Google.

Comment: I've been tearing my hair out over this for hours. I'm not sure if the documentation is bad or I'm just an idiot, but surely they should note that metadata is a jquery plugin. It's great how your comment, 2 years later, managed to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

here what I've done:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: 'fancyNumber',
        is:function(s){return false;},
        format: function(s) {return s.replace(/[\,\.]/g,'');},
        type: 'numeric'
    });
    $("table").tablesorter({headers: {0: {sorter: 'fancyNumber'}}});
});
```

worked with comma and dot separator.

test it http://jsbin.com/equci5

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked for me.
In the tablesorter.js, modify the *formatFloat()* function as follows:

```
this.formatFloat = function (s) {
            var i = parseFloat(s.replace(/[,]/g, ''));
            return (isNaN(i)) ? 0 : i;
        };
```

This will replace the commas which were interfering with the sorting.
Found the answer [here](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/tablesorter-plugin-wrong-sort-with-thousands-separators).
Hope this helps...!

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly assigning the parser in the .tablesorter() declaration.

```
.tablesorter( { headers: { 0: { sorter:'fancyNumber' } });
```

[See the source](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)

Comment: Because of how I generate my columns and the columns allowed to be chosen by the user, I would never know which header is in and not.  I have tried using the class="{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}"  command as stated here: http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-meta-parsers.html

Comment: I can see that. Is tablesorter using a different parser for the "fancyNumber" columns? Would it be smart to move the parsers creation above the other ones so that it gets first crack at the column, in case one of the other parsers is being selected first?

Comment: Jared, How would I know if its using a different parser?

I am using the mini version of the sorter so I can't exactly put this parser up front...

My thought is that its looking at it like a number for some rows and a number with a comma for others...  For some reason, its just not working correctly..

Comment: Here's the debug steps I would try:
1) In Firebug Console (or whatever) make sure that the regex triggers a true on the first value in the column
2) Make sure the replace is working correctly to strip the commas out
3) Try the "unminified" version and put the parser as the second one (after text) and see if that works--if so, it'll be a little trickier to work around.

Answer (score 0):

As Jared has mentioned, you need to specify which column uses which Parser, if you don't know the index of the column then you can find it our using this:

```
var fancyIndex = $('th.fancyColumn').prevAll().length
var headers = {};
headers[fancyIndex] = {sorter:'fancyNumber'}

$("table").tablesorter({headers:headers})
```

Comment: Ducky, the second line is not working...  It says its missing a ; at the location 

[

where the header is declared.

Comment: @Scott try now, I forgot to add var headers = {}; line

Comment: @ducky, Nope, still not happening.  One I used your idea, another column that was sorting incorrectly started working correctly.  Maybe its just this column thats having trouble...

Maybe its because there is a integer and a comma separated integer in the same column?

Comment: try slapping semicolons on the end of every line.

Answer (score 0):

I, try this regular expression: /(\d{1,3})?(\,\d{3})*/

Answer (score 0):

The parsers only look at the first tbody row to detect which parser to use. I'm guessing your first row doesn't have any commas in it. I ran into the same problem, and finally just forced the parser I wanted, using class="{sorter: 'fancyNumber'}"

Answer (score 0):

You are completely correct that the parser should be working, the reason it is not is due to a bug in the plugin. In short the plugin thinks it can sort numbers with commas in them correctly, and so uses its built in sorter, but then fails to sort them correctly.

There are a few ways to fix it.

Firstly you can (as you suggested above) force the use of your sorting function (either in the  or in the javascript on initialisation of the plugin).

Secondly you can edit the plugin to use your functions in preference to your own, this can be achieved by reversing the direction of the for loop on line 220 of the plugin.

Thirdly you can fix the broken default sorting behaviour by modifying either the digit detection function to not accept commas (line 861 of the plugin) or by modifying the default number sorter to handle commas (line 852 of the plugin).

I have raised this issue on the tablesorter google code page: http://code.google.com/p/tablesorter/issues/detail?id=6

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. In the tablesorter.js, modify the formatFloat() function as follows:

```
this.formatFloat = function (s) {
            s = s.toString();
            var i = parseFloat(s.replace(/[,]/g, ''));
            return (isNaN(i)) ? 0 : i;
        };
```

This will replace the commas which were interfering with the sorting. Found the answer here. Hope this helps...!