# jQuery tablesorter sorting is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

This is my code for jQuery tablesorter:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sorttable").tablesorter()
                   .tablesorterPager({ container: $("#pagerOne"), positionFixed: false })
    });
</script>
```

The data is like this:

```
14.6km,about:21 mins
12.6km,about:41 mins
9.6km,about:15 mins
5.6km,about:5 mins
140.6km,about:3 hours 21 mins
```

Like that above, how to sort the above type of data, please give me any solution.

Problem is data is not sorted, just jumping the data.

Please help fix this problem.

```
<table id="sorttable" class="yui" width="580px" style="display: block; ">
<thead><tr><th align="center" class="header headerSortDown"><a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">sort1</a></th><th align="center" class="header"><a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">sort2</a></th><th align="center" class="header"> <a href="#" title="Click Header to Sort">sort3</a></th></tr></thead>

 <tbody><tr><td><span id="Labe1" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore1" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="Near Santhi sagar,Koramangala,5 th block,Bangalore,Karnataka                                                                                           "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but1" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename1')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe10" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore10" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="2954 23, 2nd Stage, D Block, MKK Road, Rajaji Nagar,Bangalore,Karnataka                                                                                           "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but10" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename10')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe2" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">1,003 km,About :14 hours 42 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore2" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="No. 5, 80 ft Road,R T Nagar, Bangalore,Bangalore,                                                                                                    "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but2" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename2')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe3" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore3" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title=" 2, 80FT ROAD,1ST STAGE, 2ND BLOCK, HBR LAYOUT, K.K.HALLI, BANGALOREBANGALORE ,Bangalore,                                                                                                    "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but3" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename3')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe4" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore4" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="87, HPCL PETROL PUMPRESIDENCY ROAD  ,Bangalore,                                                                                                    "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but4" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename4')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe5" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore5" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="Mats Fuel Park,   123 2, ITPL Road, Brookefields, Kundalahalli, Bangalore - 37,Bangalore,                                                                                                    "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but5" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename5')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe6" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">1,005 km,About :14 hours 39 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore6" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title=" 124 2, C O HPCL PETROL PUMP, BYRASANDRA ROAD, DRDO TOWNSHIP, C V  RAMAN NAGAR, BANGALORE ,Bangalore,                                                                                                    "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but6" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename6')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe7" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore7" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="17 7, SANTOSH PETROL PUMPNEW BEL ROAD, CHIKKAMARANAHALLI  ,Bangalore,Karnataka                                                                                           "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but7" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename7')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe8" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">1,001 km,About :14 hours 39 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore8" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="No. 6, 100 ft Road,1st Stage,Indiranagar,Bangalore,Karnataka                                                                                           "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but8" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename8')"></td></tr>
<tr><td><span id="Labe9" style="display:inline-block;color:Sienna;height:30px;width:250px;">993 km,About :14 hours 27 mins</span></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><img id="lblstore9" src="Blue%20hills.jpg" style="height:30px;width:40px;" title="52, HPCL PETROL PUMP15TH CROSS, 1ST PHASE JPNAGAR  ,Bangalore,Karnataka                                                                                           "></td><td align="center" style="width: 150px; "><input id="but9" type="button" value="View" style="height:30px;width:75px;" onmouseover="viewmap('lblstorename9')"></td></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
<tr id="pagerOne"><td colspan="7"><img src="JqueryFiles/img/first.png" class="first" alt="img"><img src="JqueryFiles/img/prev.png" class="prev" alt="img"><input type="text" class="pagedisplay"><img src="JqueryFiles/img/next.png" class="next" alt="img"><img src="JqueryFiles/img/last.png" class="last" alt="img"><select class="pagesize"><option selected="selected" value="10">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="60">60</option><option value="70">70</option><option value="80">80</option></select></td></tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

and also here 1,5,10 records are not sorting...

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051869/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051869/tablesorter-pager-initial-pagination)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are attempting to do with the sorting on the other columns... If you want custom sort order for the images or buttons you can use one of their attributes for the sort order using a custom text extraction method.

I'll assume that your main goal is to sort the rows by distance numerically. To do this use a custom parser to pull out the first word of the string and remove the commas before comparing numerically.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YqsU/1/) for a simplified example using your data sorting numerically by distance.

See also:

- [JQuery TableSorter Comma-Digit Parser not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876092/jquery-tablesorter-comma-digit-parser-not-working)
- [Tablesorter custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)
- [Tablesorter custom text extraction](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html)